# Why does a class implements interface not describe the argument and response types of the class methods?

Tags: typescript

If I have a User class that has a method for creating user the class implements an interface that describes that class, shouldn't my interface be able to provide the method arguments and responses?

My User class looks like this:

```
interface UserModalInterface {
  createUser: (user: UserInput) => Promise<DDBUser>
}

class UserModel implements UserModalInterface {

  public async createUser(user: UserInput): Promise<DDBUser> {
    // do somethiing
  }

}
```

As you can see, I have to explicitly state that my `user` argument of `createUser` is of type `UserInput`. I have to define that in both the `createUser` method and `UserModalInterface`.

If I remove the `UserInput` from the `createUser` method then the type becomes implied `any`. But I would have thought that because my `UserModel` class implements `UserModalInterface` then the types would be inferred by the interface?

Maybe there is some TS config that can assist with this or is it just not possible in TS?

My TypeScript config looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "target": "es2021",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": false,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

Why does my class interface not describe the argument and response types of my class methods?

I have looked at [Implementing a Typescript class interface does not preserve method types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60308798/implementing-a-typescript-class-interface-does-not-preserve-method-types) but it doesn't answer my question. It links to some threads but even the author of the post hasn't selected an answer as correct which suggests no appropriate answer has been given.

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/60308798/3001761?

Comment: Not really. I can see there are several answers (none have been marked as correct) and one of them links to a GitHub issue which I can't really find the answer to either. I'm guessing by the fact that you have both linked to that previously asked question you have come across this issue before too?

Comment: From what I can ascertain from other sources is that in Java, the purpose of an interface is to define a contract or a set of behaviors that a class promises to implement. It sounds like Typescript has copied this implementation (for lack of a better word)

Comment: If you're unsatisfied with the existing answers then by all means add a bounty, but having another question isn't as useful.